# Get uploadify to work with cookieless session state?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, uploadify

I have an uploadify control working fine in a vb.net web application - however whenever I switch on cookieless session state in web.config (cookieless="true") - it stops working.

In my upload IHttpHandler I can see that the data stored by uploadify is nothing:

```
Private Function Process(ByVal context As HttpContext) As String
    Dim File As HttpPostedFile
    File = context.Request.Files("filedata") ' Nothing
    Dim FileExt As String = context.Request("fileExt") ' Nothing, etc
    ...
```

I'm guessing that the flash isn't honoring the session id in my url?  Any ideas on how to keep uploadify working when I turn on cookieless session state?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to pass your session ID manually as a  parameter.

Find your target `script` in your uploadify settings, and have your script add the session ID manually to that address.

Comment: Thanks for the help - here is specifically what worked: `$("._Uploadify", container).uploadify({ ... 'uploader':'/(S(cop34c55en03yr55eoagpcyn))/Standard/Core/Javascript/uploadify.swf', 'script': '/(S(cop34c55en03yr55eoagpcyn))/Upload'`

Of course we had to detect if cookieless session state was turned on and manually add the session id to the urls with server/client side code - but this solved our problem with cookieless session state and uploadify.  Thanks!